# Combine TextViews properly

Tags: android, xml

I would like to achieve the following:

[image]

This is what I have now however:

[image]

This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/detail"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="34sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/word"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="34sp" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/synonyms"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="17sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/line"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/Line" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/explanation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, the number, word and synonyms are seperate TextViews.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've been plating around with the widths and heights (match_parent, wrap_content, fill_parent,...) but I can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use JustifiedTextview

Comment: Problem is, I'm already using my own CustomFontTextView (left them out of the example). Also, I'm using Xamarin so I don't know if I can use it then?

Comment: in your xml all i can see is normal textviews,and i am not saying about font,i am saying about justification of your text

Comment: Yes, like I said, I left them out for simplicity. All TextViews are actually MyProject.CustomFontTextViews I wrote myself.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the xml outlay for your requirement **(Not exactly xml)**. **You need to make necessary changes in xml.** *I have made layout for elements above your blue line* 
 I have ordered it with respective numbers.

---

Base will be Linear Layout (width = match_parent) of horizontal orientation

---

(1) TextView for Number 
(2) Relative Layout for the following (2.1 , 2.2, 2.3)

---

2.1) TextView (@+id/txtWord) with top aligned wrap_content 
2.2) TextView below (@txtWord) for Syn3 which will be (@+id/txtSyn3)
2.3) TextView for Syn4 (layout_toRightOf @txtSyn3)

---

3) TextView for Synonym1
4) TextView for Syn2

Comment: Problem is some words have no synonyms and some have one. I have to have a view that adapts to the info that is displayed.

Comment: @FreeRedneckKiss You mean even if no text is available for a specific view, you still need to assign space?   Can you try out my logic and see if it works?

Comment: Ok, I will. What do you mean with "TextView (@+id/txtWord) with top aligned wrap_content "?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to achieve your layout.
Make your `word` and `synonyms` in same `TextView`

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="34sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/wordandSynonyms"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your Java code

```
wordandSynonyms.setText(Html.fromHtml("<big><font color=\"#0000ff\">" + "World" + "</font></big>" + "<font color=\"#ff0000\">" + "-synonyms1 synonyms2"+ "</font>"));
```

You can see here http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html
to know which `html tag` is support for `TextView`. 
Hope this help

Comment: Can I still give them different fonts then?

Comment: Yes, you can modify it in font tag

Comment: No, I mean word and synonyms. Since they're in the same TextView, I can't give them different fonts, no?

Comment: in my Java code, the word is blue (0000ff) and the synonyms is red(ff0000)

Comment: Yes, but I mean fonts. Like MyFont.ttf, now I use a CustomFontTextView to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by putting the word and synonyms in the same TextView. Next, I created a CustomTypefaceSpan and used it with ISpannable to edit the font, size and style.